# I want to sort the characters in a string using bubble sort. What is wrong with this code?

Tags: c, string, bubble-sort

```
/* gets a string */
printf("Enter the string: ");
scanf("%s", s);

/* finds length of the string */
while(s[size]!='\0')
{
    size++;
}

/* sorts the elements of the string using bubble sort */
for(j=0; j<size-1; j++)
{
    for(i=0; i<(size-1-i); i++)
    {
        if(s[i]>s[i+1])
        {
            temp=s[i];
            s[i]=s[i+1];
            s[i+1]=temp;
        }
    }

    /* displays pass by pass output */
    printf("\nIteration %d\n", j+1);
    printf("%s\n", s);
}

return 0;
```

This is the output I am getting -

Enter the string: computer

Iteration 1
cmoputer

Iteration 2
cmoputer

Iteration 3
cmoputer

Iteration 4
cmoputer

Iteration 5
cmoputer

Iteration 6
cmoputer

Iteration 7
cmoputer

Please correct the code and tell me the mistake. Thanks!

Comment: Please explain this `size-1-i`. Try `j`.

Comment: I think it's simpler to understand bubble sort using a `while swapped` condition rather than `loop n times`.

Comment: Thank you guys for your inputs! Corrected the mistake and it works fine now... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
size-1-i
```

scan only to half of the word "cmoputer".
That half is already sorted.

Change to

```
size-1-j
```

Answer (score 1):

In the inner for loop, change the condition to `(size-j-1)`.

Comment: Please explain the added insight of you answer, compared to the older comment and the older answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have done a silly mistake in second inner loop's ***termination condition***.
You should change second loop to following:  `for(i=0; i<(size-1-j); i++)`.

Comment: Please explain the added insight of you answer, compared to the older comment and the older answers.

Answer (score 1):

The condition `i < (size-1-i)` is equal to `2 * i < size - 1`, also equal to `i < (size - 1) / 2`.

As a consequence, that loop only iterates over half the word.

This should be either `i < size - 1`, or `i < size - 1 - j` (slight optimization, not really necessary, if you want to optimize, you don't bubble sort)